# How to edit product data tab in WooCommerce backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I need to reorder WooCommerce Product data tab in admin panel.

I need to move general tab under inventory tab. Can anyone please advise me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the following filter, and swap the priority numbers

```php
function my_product_data_tabs( $product_data_tabs ) {
    $product_data_tabs['inventory']['priority'] = 10; // first
    $product_data_tabs['general']['priority'] = 20; // second

    return $product_data_tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'my_product_data_tabs', 10, 1 );
```

*Other priority numbers*

shipping = 30

linked_product = 40

attribute = 50

variations = 60

advanced = 70